# NativeScript Angular back to previous route instead of pushing it as new page

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I use one of the ns-angular demo apps. Back functionality works fine with hardware back button. It means it remove current page and back to previous page. But with code, NativeScript team has such implementation:

```
<NavigationButton [nsRouterLink]="['../../home']" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
```

But it's not a actual back. It pushes home page as a new page. (And when I use hardware back button, I see too many back and forward pages)

Comment: can you please explain more and possible add images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i get what you are trying to say , but here is some short explanation about Angular routing .

when you tap on a element with an RouterLink its will navigate to the route .

`<button [nsRouterLink]="['home']">`
The code above will navigate to the home route and the component will loaded (the ngOnInit will fire)

`<button[nsRouterLink]="['home' , 'test']">`

this will navigate to /home/test

when i tap the back button (on android) it will go back to the last route and it will not fire the ngOnInit

Im hope i helped if you can write again what is youre problem and maybe add some images it will be great